# Displaying a constantly changing variable in a text box in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

i want to create a text box in excel vba that will display the value of a changing variable till a final value is reached. Here is the code that i wrote

```
**For i= 0 to CWPRES_MAX step 0.1  
  CW_PRESSURE.value = i (CW_PRESSURE is the name of my text box)         
  Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
  Next**
```

I want variable i to count up to the value CWPRES_MAX in steps of 0.1 and at each step the value to be displayed in the text box (CW_PRESSURE). but while running, the program is executing the entire delay and finally displaying the final value of 'i', that is CWPRES_MAX in the text box.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

Google DoEvents

```
  For i= 0 to CWPRES_MAX step 0.1  

  DoEvents

  CW_PRESSURE.value = i (CW_PRESSURE is the name of my text box)         
  Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

  Next
```